# Constraining the area for text in an UILabelView

Tags: objective-c, text, uilabel

I've got a UILabelView that takes up a large amount of space (and it has to do this).
However, I want the text within it to stay within a small area within it.  I've had a look around, and I see there is a method fro containing the area text can occupy in a text view - is there something similar for UILabelView?  So I can keep text within a CGRect of the label view?
Thanks for your help,
Sam

Comment: Why don't you just use a `UIView` with a `UILabel` in it? Explain what you need the `UILabelView` to take up a large amount of space for.

Comment: It has to take up the space because of an animation I'm running.

Comment: How does this space taking-up facilitate your animation? It seems like you should use a `UIView` to take up space and a `UILabel` to show your text.

Comment: Sticking with the large labelView, can I use something along the lines of: textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:?

Comment: I just found it in the class reference for iOS (I was accidentally looking in the Mac one before).

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to constrict words to a specific space inside a `UILabel`. Because `UILabel` is just a very basic way to display a small amount of text, it seems unlikely.

Comment: What is the behavior that you are seeing if you put too much text in? It should either be autoshrinking (if you had it set to do so) or clipping the text.

Comment: It was clipping it.  I found out how to do what I wanted without modifying UILabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Dustin - basically it looks like the only way is to put it into a view.